# iOS build: command ld failed with a nozero exit code

Tags: xcode, react-native-ios

For a react-native project, I got the following error during Xcode build:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/user172615/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-appletvsimulator/libBVLinearGradient.a'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code`

This happened after adding `react-native-linear-gradient`, and following the instructions in https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient (manual installation for iOS).

1. As specified in https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#manually, libBVLinearGradient.a is included in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` for the target `myProject`
2. libBVLinearGradient.a is also included in `General -> Frameworks, Libraries and embedded content`.
3. I tried deleting DerivedData, and rebuilding. Didn't help.
4. Since the error indicates `Debug-appletvsimulator`, I included libBVLinearGradient.a in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` for the target `myProject-tvOS`
5. When this didn't help, I deleted the `myProject-tvOS` target. All didn't help.

I am using Xcode 11.3, react-native 0.59.9.

Any idea?

Comment: Is `libBVLinearGradient.a` library present somewhere and included to your iOS target?

Comment: Yes, in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and General -> Frameworks, Libraries and embedded content . I updated the question with some more details.

Answer (score -1):

1. Instead of downloading it, do this instead.

Click on clone existing project

[image]

Then copy this link

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

And paste the link here

[image]

Then it will download the project.

**If the problem still happens, then create a new project, copy and paste everything.**

Comment: Paste the link where?

Comment: Paste the link on the top

Comment: On the top of what? :) In package.json?

Comment: When you press clone from git respiratory, there will be a text field; in there you paste the link

Comment: Ok... But I don't want to create a new repo, but use my own that is already working on android. Any suggestion for what I should do for an existing project?